# convert unix double to date and extract the years

Tags: r, unix-timestamp

i will convert this unix timestemp to date, how can i do that?

[image]

```
food%>%
  mutate(date=as.integer(created_t))
  head(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(food$date)), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT"))
```

Comment: Something like this? `food%>%
  mutate(date=as.POSIXct(as.numeric(created_t), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")) %>% 
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(date))`

Comment: dont work... 
Error in as.POSIXct(as.numeric(created_t), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT") : 
  unused arguments (origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")

Comment: Whoever edited the question adding the `mutate` made no sense.  Why create `date` via `as.integer` only to convert it again `as.character`?  Also `mutate` is not base R, and the required `library(dplyr)` is not shown so it won't work as posted.  Anyway....

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with base commands to a) convert to a datetime object and b) extract (or format) out the year and optionally turn it to `integer`:

```
> as.integer(format(as.POSIXct(create_t, origin="1970-01-01"), "%Y"))
[1] 2017 2018 2018
>
```

Different ad-on packages have helpers too but the simplicity of a base R solution is good too.

And next time please do *not* post *images* of your data but an assignment to reproducible data as I did here for the first three data points.

#### Detailed Code Step by Step

```
## data
create_t <- c(1489527029, 1533734197, 1533734197)

## as datetime
as.POSIXct(create_t, origin="1970-01-01")

## extract year
format(as.POSIXct(create_t, origin="1970-01-01"), "%Y")

## extract year as integer
as.integer(format(as.POSIXct(create_t, origin="1970-01-01"), "%Y"))
```

#### Output

```
> create_t <- c(1489527029, 1533734197, 1533734197)
> as.POSIXct(create_t, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2017-03-14 16:30:29 CDT" "2018-08-08 08:16:37 CDT" "2018-08-08 08:16:37 CDT"
> format(as.POSIXct(create_t, origin="1970-01-01"), "%Y")
[1] "2017" "2018" "2018"
> as.integer(format(as.POSIXct(create_t, origin="1970-01-01"), "%Y"))
[1] 2017 2018 2018
>
```

#### Alternate data.table solution

```
> suppressMessages(library(data.table))
> D <- data.table(create_t = create_t)
> D[, pt := as.POSIXct(create_t, origin="1970-01-01")][, y := year(pt)]
> D
     create_t                  pt    y
1: 1489527029 2017-03-14 16:30:29 2017
2: 1533734197 2018-08-08 08:16:37 2018
3: 1533734197 2018-08-08 08:16:37 2018
>
```

Comment: i have the error "object created_t" not found? why??

food%>%
  as.integer(format(as.POSIXct(created_t, origin="1970-01-01"), "%Y"))

Comment: Because you have a typo where you could have _copied_ my code; I called the variable `create_t`, not `created_t`.  Another reason for you to start with a _reproducible_ example. When I recreated you data from the _screenshot_ I wrote it as `create_t` -- that's all.

Comment: in my table i called the variable created_t and have the error created_t not found

Comment: Just _copy and paste the code I offered you_. I ran it before posting. It works. Maybe you can adjust it to your needs by renaming one variable.

Comment: i have copied the code and have in r stuido the error bot found

Comment: So either change the initial variable to `create_t`, or equally change the example I posted to `created_t` to match the variable you have.  Changing _one character_ should not be such a roadblock.

Comment: i have change the varibale name to created_t, that is not the problem but the problem is that i habe the erorr not found

Comment: food%>%
  mutate(date= as.Date(from_unixtime(created_t)))%>%
  select(product_name, date)

i have convert it so, but can you help me to extract the year

Comment: I posted a working answer, plus a working alternate.

Comment: Also: learning to debug by _simplifying_ is good.  Just try the expression _without a variable_:  `as.integer(format(as.POSIXct(1489527029, origin="1970-01-01"), "%Y"))`.  Then build it up from there.